# Github commit message when deploying to aws beanstalk in Jenkins

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am running a Jenkins job that deploys to aws beanstalk, I want in the description to have the the commit message and I am using ${GIT_COMMIT} env variable.
What I am getting is the commit hash and not the message.
I've installed the Git Tag Message plugin and enabled it in Additional Behaviours in source code management.
I am using the ${GIT_TAG_MESSAGE} in the aws deploy stage and it's not recognized.
I am using a freestyle project.
I've tried to capture the following commands:
git log -1 --oneline $GIT_COMMIT
git log -1 --pretty='%s' $GIT_COMMIT

But can't seem to capture it.
This is what I am getting:
[wp-az] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins6734038198136655184.sh
++ git log -1 --pretty=%s cdb858f3b84328184c6f83a2e79e8571a63d814c
+ Update README.md

I don't think we are taging our commits in github.

Would appreciate any assistance on how to deliever the commit message.

[pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGB4s.png)
[pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMjkA.png)

Edit:
I am able to get the commit message but I can't seem to deliver 
The new variable with the aws beanstalk deploy plugin.
I've uploaded two new pics.

Would appreciate more comments

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are able to get the commit hash. you can get the message like this:

```
git show -s --format=%B commithash
```

For example:

```
git show -s --format=%B 3e7cf2a7c22
```

If you want the last commit you can use your env var:
[image]

OUTPUT:

[image]

**EDIT**

You can use the [environment script](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Environment+Script+Plugin) plugin to add the env var:
[image]

Comment: I added pictures.
Not sure what to run first and how to deliver the parameter

Comment: @Ivthillo I've edited two new pics,
Thanks for all your help

Comment: @Amits does echo $MESSAGE already work in an execute shell step? + what is the name of the plugin you're using to deploy. Can you try to put MESSAGE in it instead of $MESSAGE?

Comment: @Ivthillo echo $MESSAGE work perfect in shell step, it brings me the commit message.
I am using AWS Elastic Beanstalk Deployment Plugin.
I've tried all this:
MESSAGE
$MESSAGE
$(MESSAGE)
${MESSAGE}

Comment: Try ${ENV,var="MESSAGE"}

Comment: It's strange
When I look in beanstalk it's empty,
The job is successful but the commit message doesn't transfer,

Comment: I have no Elastic beanstalk to test so I can't help you further. Sorry